# get null response from node in angular7 using subscribe function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean-stack

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  console.log(username, "===> username");
  console.log(password, "===> password");

      User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username,
        },function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(502).send({
            "Message": "Db error",
            "error": err
          });
          console.log("login if");
        }
        //console.log("log",user)
            if (user) {
              if (user.username === req.body.username && user.password == req.body.password) {
                    var token = jwt.sign({
                      username: req.body.username,
                    },process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                        expiresIn: parseInt(process.env.EXPIRY_TIME)
                      });
                    res.send({
                      Message: "logged in sucessfully",
                      Token: token
                    })
              }
            } else {
                res.status(404).send({
                Message: "not found",
                })
              }
      });

});
```

//above code is of server side it sends response to postman and also sends true to client but cant send object
//and below code is of login.component.ts file

```
 login() {
     this.loginservice.authenticate(this.username, this.password)
        .subscribe((res) => {
              console.log(" user is",res);
              localStorage.setItem("user",res.toString());
                this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            }, (error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
}
```

//and the last code is of service 
  authenticate(username, password) {

```
  const url = environment.binanceserver + '/users/login';
    console.log("Endpoint being hit", url, username, password);
    const obj = {
      "username": username,
      "password": password
    }
    return this.http.post(url, obj);
```

Comment: 1. what is the error that you are getting? 2. What is the output of `console.log('user id',res)` ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a Content-type header?

Comment: 1 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: 2 res is null ,,,

Comment: Are you sure that `req.body` is not empty (when request is handled by server)?

Comment: You have to use [this](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware to avoid cors issues with express

Comment: response displayed in postman

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS from the server side to accept request from other origins. You can use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to enable CORS in express/node.

Comment: thats not matter I enabled cors chrome extension